# Key server times out while installing docker on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install docker on Ubuntu 14.04, however, I can't get beyond the first step documented here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.VB8X4gv8Ty --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
gpg: requesting key 2C52609D from hkp server p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

The key server is timing out after couple of minutes of running this command. Anyone else facing this issue? I saw some [posts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75892/keyserver-timed-out-when-trying-to-add-a-gpg-public-key) about firewalls blocking port 11371. But I'm already using port 80, so that shouldn't be the issue.

What can I do to update the keys manually on Ubuntu if the preferred option of getting it from the key server with apt-key is not working?

Comment: I would take this question to the AskUbuntu or ServerFault.

Comment: Looks like it's down again.

Answer (score 6):

Try this key server "hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80"

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D

It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

At the time of this writing, http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net reports `p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net` as being down.

That would explain the error message.

---

Update an hour later, the `p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net` is reported up again.

The [OP rkrishnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059404/rkrishnan) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760945/key-server-times-out-while-installing-docker-on-ubuntu-14-04/34761335?noredirect=1#comment57270623_34761335) get docker installed using `apt-get install docker-engine`

Comment: For me downforeveryoneorjustme showed the key server as up and running. Anyway, I could get docker installed using `apt-get install docker-engine`.

Comment: @rkrishnan Hence the "at the time of this writing" :) It is no longer down right now.

Comment: @rkrishnan I have edited the answer to make that clear, and to include your comment for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Install docker using `apt-get install docker-engine` and it worked for me. Wonder why this is not the default documented option in docker docs!